# Android:MapActivity is giving Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mapview, mapactivity

when i first load my app mapActivity is invoking and i can see the map, now when i
switch off the networkconnectivity and on again , changing the screen and coming back 
to the mapactivity the map is showing null, getting nullpointer exception at this 
line new `MapUtils().drawMap(this);` in `onResume()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new ManageLocation();

    listener.setSucessCallBack(this, "setLocation");
    listener.setFailureCallBack(this, "setNoLocation");


    manager.requestLocationUpdates(
            utils.getCurrentPlaceLocationProvider(manager), 0, 0,
            listener);
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "Constants.isDataLoadedPAB " + Constants.isMaptobeLoaded
            + " Constants.isDataLoadedPAB : " + Constants.isDataLoadedPAB);
    if (Constants.isMaptobeLoaded) {
        if (Constants.isDataLoadedPAB) {
            try {
                new MapUtils().drawMap(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            }
        } else {
            if (Constants.currentLocation != null
                    && Constants.searchLocation != null) {
                if (Constants.searchResultData == null) {
                    Constants.searchResultData = new ArrayList<AttractionData>();
                }

                new MapUtils().drawMap(this);

            }
            }
    }
    ((ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.left)).setEnabled(true);
    ((ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.right)).setEnabled(true);   
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchicon)).setEnabled(true);

    ((ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.facebookintegration)).setEnabled(true);
}
```

I am trying to invoke it again in `onResume()` but still getting null. 
i am struck not sure where i am doing wrong.Any help is appreciated

my log

```
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at org.appright.myneighborhood.maps.MapUtils.drawMap(MapUtils.java:59)
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at org.appright.myneighborhood.activity.CityAttractions.onResume(CityAttractions.java:505)
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
01-29 11:23:36.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: you spelt Success Sucess - would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @RachelGallen the method is sucess only not success

Comment: It seems from logcat there is an `null exception` in `MapUtils().drawMap(this)`. can you show the function of `MapUtils().drawMap(this)`

Comment: @AnimeshSinha  here is the mapUtils code http://pastebin.com/JTL25pHz at line 13 i am getting exception

Comment: Does your `xml layout` file contain `defaultmapView` naming MapView in it?

Comment: @AnimeshSinha  yes..here is the layout   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/defaultmapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:apiKey="@string/apikey"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true" />

Comment: Does `defaultmapView` comes under `FrameLayout map_container` in xml ?

Comment: @AnimeshSinha yes it is under FrameLayout..plz have alook http://pastebin.com/p7MPRyDH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
FrameLayout topLayout = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.map_container);
                    topLayout.removeAllViews();
```

in `MapUtils().drawMap(this);`

what you are doing is to remove all the view from container i.e. `FrameLayout map_container`
when `network connection` not available.

And when network comes again you are accessing the `MapView` which you have removed **from the layout  hierarchy** and it wont find the `defaultmapView` this time and throw `NullPionterException`.

Try to comment all the code in `else` block and just show a toast only. hope it will work. Or try some different logic.